# Binding class with empty string as navigation path doesn't update

Tags: vb.net, binding

I'm using vb .net in vs2005

As a simplified example, I'm binding an object to a textbox like this

```
Dim tobject as object
Dim WithEvents obinding As Binding
Private Sub mySub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    tobject = "string"
    obinding = New Binding("text", tobject, "")
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(obinding)
End Sub
```

From this msdn info it appears that this should work?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx

"If you set the navigation path to an empty string, the ToString method will be called on the underlying data source object"

When I run the sub, the textbox does indeed update to reflect the value of tobject, but subsequent changes to tobject don't update the textbox

For some background, since this is probably unusual. Let's just call it an exercise in understanding the capabilities of the language. I know that I can create a custom class and bind to that but then I'd have to refer a property

```
tobject.value = some_value
```

or an indexer if value was the default property

```
tobject(1) = some_value
```

whereas I just want to refer to the object (and have it data bound)

```
tobject = some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object` does not support `INotifyPropertyChanged` so it will not tell the binding to refresh the value.

If you create your own class, as you mentioned you could have done, your will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in it as well, if you want this to work this way.